# How secure would this be using AES in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, aes, mcrypt

```
$key = md5('secret password'); 
// this ^ would be supplied by the user every login, never stored
Crypt::setKey($key);
$encrypted = Crypt::encrypt('secret message'); 
// this ^ would be stored in a database
$decrypted = Crypt::decrypt($encrypted);
return $decrypted;
```

Would this be any more secure than just passing the plain text for the key? I'm wondering how secure this would be for storing sensitive data.

Answer (score 1):

If somebody knows the algorithm you're using (That is, just md5) then it's just as secure as the "secret password."  It may help a tiny bit if the encoded message is compromised, but even more secure would be hashing the "secret password" with a salt.  If you're really serious about keeping this "secret message" secure, you could use the password_hash function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to encode the key before encrypting the message.

Comment: Whats really the point in using AES in this manner? If I were to use the application key by default for encryption, someone could just get in to my server and grab the key and everything would be able to be decrypted.

Comment: If the key is a user input, and you then password_hash the key before encrypting with it, it's pretty DANG secure, provided the user input (a password) is not reused all over the place or anything.  password_hash is designed to take a really long time to brute-force.

Comment: I think I see what you were getting at, though:  A static key, put into the page, is a bad idea to encode with.  Like you said, somebody could get and make use of that.  A variable key (like a user input) is good - provided it's not stored anywhere - and the password_hash is probably overkill.

Comment: @Helpful Overkill? pffff. No way. I would recommend password_hash any day over md5. md5 can be brute forced extremely fast.

Comment: This would never be stored anywhere, it would be something the user memorizes and puts in to decrypt data. Also, password hash doesnt work because these aes keys cant be that long.

Comment: @Mike, I absolutely agree with you.  if this were for storing passwords in a database I'd curse against md5 until I turned blue.  However, since this is just being used as an encryption key, and is (hopefully) not being stored anywhere, the passcode itself doesn't need any ridiculous protections - bruteforce attempts will be made against the encrypted message, not a hash of the password.  Though password_hash will make the message considerably more secure if the encrypted message is compromised.

Comment: @Helpful You're right. I now see that the hash isn't actually stored anywhere.

Comment: @Helpful Although you could just use password_hash with a low cost parameter (like 7-8) and it shouldn't negatively affect anything and still add a bit more security, like you said, if it's ever compromised.

Comment: An excellent idea.  Depends on the version of PHP he's running, of course, but more security rarely hurts.